# How to get numbers from html?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to get

1. the number after: page=
2. the number after: "new">
3. the number after: /a>-

   ```
   <td> </td>
   <td> qwqwqwqwqw <br/> qwqwqwqwqw  <a href="http://url.pdf#page=99" target="new">4449</a>-4450<br/> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> qwqwqwqwqw <br/> qwqwqwqwqw  <a href="http://url.pdf#page=77" target="new">5111</a>-5550<br/> </td>
   <td> </td>
   ...
   ```

My code

```
tables = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'target': 'new'})
```

gives my only a list (see below) without the third number

```
[<a href="http://url.pdf#page=99" target="new">4449</a>,
 <a href="http://url.pdf#page=77" target="new">5111</a>,
...]
```

her is how i would try to  extract the 3 numbers from my list, once it has the third digit in it.

```
list_of_number1 = []
list_of_number2 = []
list_of_number3 = []
regex = re.compile("page=(\d+)")
for table in tables:
    number1 = filter(regex.match, tables)
    number2 = table.next_sibling.strip()
    number3 =
    list_of_number1.append(number1)
    list_of_number2.append(number2)
    list_of_number3.append(number3)
```

Do i use beautifulsoup for the third number or is it feasible to regex through the whole html for any number following "/a>-"

Comment: If you need to get a number after `a` tag, why use `soup.find_all('a', attrs={'target': 'new'})`? You need to target `td` elements, and that might also require targeting a specific table. The question is too vague right now, unless you confirm you just want to extract the numbers from `a` tags with the specified attributes and then a number right after that tag in any `td` element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i confirm that i only want the two numbers from those specific `a` tags with `attrs={'target': 'new'}` and only the number following only those `a` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can obtain your result using just the information that you need to get the numbers in the specific `a` element and in the text node immediately on the right:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tables = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'target': 'new'})
print([(t.text, t["href"].split('=')[-1], t.next_sibling.replace('-', '')) for t in tables])
# => [('4449', '99', '4450'), ('5111', '77', '5550')]
```

You may certainly go the harder way with regexps:

```py
import re
#... the same initialization code as above
for t in tables:
    page = ""
    page_m = re.search(r"[#?]page=(\d+)", t["href"])
    if page_m:
        page = page_m.group(1)
    else:
        page = ""
    num = "".join([x for x in t.next_sibling if x.isdigit()])
    results.append((int(t.text), int(page), int(num)))

    
print(results)
# => [(4449, 99, 4450), (5111, 77, 5550)]
```

**NOTE**:

- `t.text` - gets the element text
- `t["href"]` - gets the `href` attribute value of the `t` element
- `t.next_sibling` - gets the next node after current one that is on the same hierarchy level.

Comment: Thanks! The regex worked nearly perfect. I had to add `int(num or 0)` to `results.append` because in rare cases in the place where the third digit would have been, there were only empty strings, which i should have expected. Unfortunately the html is pretty messy and old, which is why your first solution did not work. Error: None type not callable. Note that calling `soup.find_all('a', attrs={'target': 'new'})` does not yet give me the third digit as it is part of the `br\br` and not the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
for b in soup.select('a'):
     print(b.attrs['href'].split('=')[1], b.text, b.nextSibling)
```

Output:

```
99 4449 -4450
77 5111 -5550
```